# GraphJS/Laravel/VueJS: Creating a graph in the backend and passing a function in the JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Here is a simple function that returns a JSON object which the FE uses to render a graph:

```
    public function spendPerCatalogNumber(Collection $orders, array $suppliers, array $costs, $start, $end): array
    {
        $data = DB::table('ordered_items')
            ->join('orders', 'ordered_items.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->whereIn('orders.id', $orders)
            ->whereIn('ordered_items.supplier', $suppliers)
            ->select(
                [
                    'ordered_items.supplier_sku',
                    DB::raw('SUM(ordered_items.price' . $this->concatCosts($costs, 'orders') . ') as cogs'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(ordered_items.quantity) as qty'),
                    DB::raw('(SUM(ordered_items.price::numeric) / SUM(ordered_items.quantity)) as avg'),
                ]
            )
            ->groupBy('ordered_items.supplier_sku')
            ->get();

        return [
            'options'  => [
                'title' => [
                    'fontSize' => 20,
                    'display'  => true,
                    'text'     => 'Spend per Catalog Number (Total Price)',
                ]
            ],
            'rows' => 6,
            'type' => 'Pie',
            'data' => [
                'labels' => $data->map(fn ($item) => $item->supplier_sku),
                'datasets' => [
                    [
                        'backgroundColor' => $data->map(fn () => $this->generateColor()),
                        'data'            => $data->map(fn ($item) => $this->stringToFloat($item->cogs)),
                        'label'           => 'Cost of Goods',
                        'hidden'          => true,
                    ],
                    [
                        'backgroundColor' => $data->map(fn () => $this->generateColor()),
                        'data'            => $data->map(fn ($item) => $item->qty),
                        'label'           => 'Quantity Purchased',
                    ],
                    [
                        'backgroundColor' => $data->map(fn () => $this->generateColor()),
                        'data'            => $data->map(fn ($item) => $item->avg),
                        'label'           => 'Average Unit Price',
                        'hidden'          => true,
                    ],
                    [
                        'backgroundColor' => $data->map(fn () => $this->generateColor()),
                        'data'            => $data->map(fn ($item) => $item->supplier_sku),
                        'label'           => 'Name',
                        'hidden'          => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'hasToolTip' => true,
        ];
    }
```

The only issue is that, I want to do some additional work on some graphs and not others. The problem is this would require the use of Javascript functions (depending on the required adjustment).

Something like this:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value;
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Notice the `callback` function?

How would I add this to the JSON object in the backend and have the FE use it while rendering the graph? I've tried just putting it inside quotes but that failed.